# MongoDb C# Driver - DeleteMany doesn't work with In Filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-core-2.1

I tried to delete dublicate records using MongoDb C# Driver. The script below neither raise an error nor delete any record. Any advice ?

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ApiUsers
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    
    public string UserEMail { get; set; }
}

var users = _mongoDbContext.ApiUsers.Find(f => f.UserEMail == email).ToList();
var oneUser = users[0];

var idsToDelete = users.Where(x => !x.Id.Equals(oneUser.Id)).Select(x => x.Id);
if (idsToDelete.Any())
{   //Delete Dublicates
    
    var idsToDeleteFilter = Builders<ApiUsers>.Filter.In(t => t.Id, idsToDelete);
    var result = _mongoDbContext.ApiUsers.DeleteMany(idsToDeleteFilter);
}
```

I tried also DeleteOne method like below, but it didn't work either,

```
foreach (var idToDelete in idsToDelete)                        
   _mongoDbContext.ApiChildUsers.DeleteOne(Builders<ApiChildUsers>.Filter.Eq(u => u.Id, idToDelete));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try the following approach where you get back an Id to keep and delete the rest like so:

```cs
var filter = Builders<ApiUsers>.Filter.Where(u => u.UserEMail == "test@test.com");
var projection = Builders<ApiUsers>.Projection.Expression(u=>u.Id);
var options = new FindOptions<ApiUsers, string> { Projection = projection, Limit = 1 };

var idToKeep = collection.FindSync(filter, options).ToList()[0];

collection.DeleteMany(
    u => u.UserEMail == "test@test.com" &&
         u.Id != idToKeep);
```

as a sidenote, i'd like to suggest you store the IDs in the server as `ObjectId` instead of string because it's less efficient as ObjectId only takes 12 bytes to store which would be less than the hexadecimal string representation of it.

here's a less verbose test program using mongodb.entities:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class ApiUsers : Entity
    {
        public string UserEMail { get; set; }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            await DB.InitAsync("test", "localhost");

            await new[] {
                new ApiUsers { UserEMail = "test@test.com"},
                new ApiUsers { UserEMail = "test@test.com"},
                new ApiUsers { UserEMail = "test@test.com"},
                new ApiUsers { UserEMail = "teX@teX.com"},
            }.SaveAsync();

            var idToKeep = (await DB.Find<ApiUsers, string>()
                                    .Match(u => u.UserEMail == "test@test.com")
                                    .Project(u => u.ID)
                                    .Limit(1)
                                    .ExecuteAsync())[0];

            await DB.DeleteAsync<ApiUsers>(
                u => u.UserEMail == "test@test.com" &&
                     u.ID != idToKeep);
        }
    }
}
```